# Tricky SQL Query about COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are two table with schema:

> Ships(name, yearLaunched, country, numGuns, gunSize, displacement)
>   Battles(ship, battleName, result)

A typical Ships tuple would be:

> ('New Jersey', 1943, 'USA', 9, 16, 46000)

which means that the battleship New Jersey was launched in 1943; it belonged to the USA, carried 9 guns of size 16-inch (bore, or inside diameter of the barrel), and weighted (displaced, in nautical terms) 46,000 tons.

A typical tuple for Battles is:

> ('Hood', 'North Atlantic', 'sunk')

That is, H.M.S. Hood was sunk in the battle of the North Atlantic. The other possible results are 'ok' and 'damaged'.

And here is the tricky query:
**For the battle of Surigao Strait, for each country engaged in that battle (had one or more battleships participating), give the number of its battleships that were sunk. Note: this question is very tricky. In particular, you need to deal with the (historical) case that a country engaged in the battle but did not have any ships sunk.**

What I've tried so far.

```
SELECT country,COUNT(name) 
FROM ships RIGHT JOIN battles 
      ON ships.name=battles.ship 
WHERE battleName='Battle1' AND result='sunk' 
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: I know I can use the number of all ships minus that of un-sunk ships, but I don't want to join four tables...

Comment: Nice question, you forgot to add your query?

Comment: Since this is homework, please show what you've tried and we can guide you towards the solution. We're not going to do it for you (well, I guess John Woo would, but his answer is wrong).

Comment: Sure, I tried this one:  `SELECT country,COUNT(name)
FROM ships
RIGHT JOIN battles
ON ships.name=battles.ship
WHERE battleName='Battle1'
AND result='sunk'
GROUP BY country`  but it's not tricky at all.  And I can join two ships and two battles together, but I think that cost too much.

Comment: @POPOL so you want to calculate only countries that did participate the battle but only those that has no sink ships yet (*in all battles*)?

Comment: Forget about trying to count them for the minute. Just write a query that gives you all ships that were sunk in the battle and what country they belong to. That's pretty easy. After that, you can modify the query to consider countries that participated but had no ships sunk. After that you can worry about the aggregation.

Comment: @JohnWoo I cannot understand your sentence. However, the requirement is just to show the number of sunk ships in a battle for each country, including those with no ship sunk.

Answer (score 4):

> country engaged in that battle (had one or more battleships
>   participating)

It means has at least one record in the battles where the battleName is 'Surigao Strait'. It means an `INNER JOIN`.

> give the number of its battleships that were sunk

It is a conditional count, and here is the "trick". You can use a SUM with a condition end then you can have the count of the ships sunk.

```
SELECT country,SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'sunk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalShipSunk 
FROM ships 
INNER JOIN battles 
      ON ships.name=battles.ship 
WHERE battleName='Surigao Strait'
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: that's my previous answer and someone voted in down, i was confused of this statement `you need to deal with the (historical) case that a country engaged in the battle but did not have any ships sunk`

Comment: I think that means we should display 'countryName:0' in such cases, and this query works well.  @Barmar Could you please explain why this is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the tables and I guess the relationship with is other is by `name of the ship`. try this one,

```
SELECT  a.country, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.result = 'SUNK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalSunkShips,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.result = 'OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalUNSunkShips
FROM    battles a
        INNER JOIN ships b
            ON a.ship = b.name
WHERE   b.battleName = 'Surigao Strait'
GROUP BY a.country
```

Comment: I did not see this answer before, but I think this is the correct.

Comment: @AndrásOttó because I deleted it (an hour ago) and undelete again. This has still missing point, maybe the OP is asking to calculate only countries that did participate the battle but only those that has no sink ships yet (*in all battles*), and i cannot create it since the OP didn't still answer my question.

Comment: @POPOL did you try to run this query?

Comment: @JohnWoo not yet but yours is the same as Andras's, so I think it will works well.  I'm just wondering why Barmar thought it is wrong.

Comment: @POPOL actually my first answer was wrong, I didn't add the number of ship that did not sink.

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Ships Record**

```
name                      yearLaunched  country numGuns gunSize displacement
New Jersey                      1943    USA      9       16      46000
Surigao Strait Battle ship USA  1800    USA      9       16      5000
Surigao Strait Battle ship USA  1800    USA      9       16      5000
Surigao Strait Battle ship UK   1800    UK       7       16      27000
Surigao Strait Battle ship France 1800  France   9       16      5000
Surigao Strait Battle ship Urugaya  1800 Urugaya 7       16      27000
New Jersey                       1943    UK      9       16      46000
```

**Sample Battle Record**

```
ship    battleName                                   result
Hood    North Atlantic                                sunk
Surigao Strait Battle ship USA  Surigao Strait        sunk
Surigao Strait Battle ship UK   Surigao Strait        damaged
Surigao Strait Battle ship France   Surigao Strait    ok
Surigao Strait Battle ship Urugaya  Surigao Strait    sunk
```

Is this what you are looking for

```
SELECT s.country,Count(s.name) AS Cnt
FROM ships s
JOIN (SELECT * 
        FROM Battles
        WHERE battleName='Surigao Strait' AND result='sunk' )b
ON s.name=b.ship 
GROUP BY s.country
```

**Result**

**country   Cnt**

```
Urugaya 1
USA 2
```